# send API request to IPv6 machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just want to send an API request to other machine on which API is running in development mode and that machine uses IPv6. I tried the URL in rest client

http://1102:304:5def:db00:bcff:c26:6920:cb2f/64:3000/api/books/get_book_no

but Rest Client says that the URL is invalid.Now please tell me how can I send request to that machine?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and modify your question to meet the standards outlined there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should surround IPv6 address with brackets. Like so

`http://[1102:304:5def:db00:bcff:c26:6920:cb2f/64]:3000/api/books/get_book_no`

Comment: Now rest client says   "The requested URL can't be reached"

Comment: @ZeshanButt seems there is some problem with rest-client's dependency Net::HTTP. As a way around this, you can use another gem for http request's. [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) for example. The code will be pretty much the same `http://[1102:304:5def:db00:bcff:c26:6920:cb2f/64]:3000/api/books/get_book_no`